# Why is the Accelerated Failure Time (AFT) model called "Accelerated"?

Tags: regression, survival

In Survival Analysis, I was reading about the parametric "Accelerated" Failure Time (AFT) model : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_failure_time_model

Reading a few sources, no where does it seem to mention why exactly this model is called "Accelerated". **Does anyone know why this model is called "Accelerated"** and what exactly is the "Acceleration" referring to in this model?

Thanks!

Comment: How about the last paragraph of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_failure_time_model#Model_specification which is what you have already linked to? Do you suspect there is more? Do you have something in mind?

Comment: @ Frank: thank you for your reply! After reading the wikipedia article, I don't understand why it is necessary to call these models as "Accelerated Failure Time" and not just "Failure Time" models. Maybe this is just a semantics issue? Thanks!

Comment: I would suspect so, too.